# MS Excel 2010 - VBA to lookup in one column a customer number and Tag the corresponding column with Yes or No

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an extremely large dataset with customer numbers and we cannot just use a     `=IF(E3=160248, "YES", "NO")` to tag a particular customer number of 160248 with YES or NO. Instead, I would like to use VBA code to lookup Customer_Number in column E and return a YES or NO in the corresponding row in Column AG, called Incorporated_160248. I have not done an If then clause in VBA, so I have no idea where to start. Please note, each month the data set can change. One month it could be 4,000 entries and the next 3,500, so that has to be dynamic.  Any thoughts?

[image]

```
Sub TagTryco()


Dim CN As Integer, result As String
CN = Range("E:E").Value

  If CN = 160248 Then
    result = "YES"
  Else
    result = "NO"
  End If

  Range("AG:AG").Value = result

  End Sub
```

I get a Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

This CODE Works now:

```
Sub TagTryco()

Dim listLength
listLength = Worksheets("ILS_Import").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To listLength + 2
   If Worksheets("ILS_Import").Range("E" & i) = 160248 Then
     Worksheets("ILS_Import").Range("AG" & i) = "Yes"
   Else
     Worksheets("ILS_Import").Range("AG" & i) = "No"
   End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: How to write an `If...Then...` statement, [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html), [here](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-if-statement/), and [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php), among many others that come up in a Google search for `excel vba if statement`. Give it a shot & post your best attempt, someone will help you fix it, but you're not likely to find many who will write it for you.

Comment: You cannot take the value from a range. So trying to the whole column's value will not work. Other than that, it was not a bad try. Check my answer to see how to see the values in a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know how many entries you have:

```
dim listLength
listlength = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1 'I assumed column E, starting at row 2
```

You need to loop from row 2 to the row 2 + listLength, check the cell in column E, and check if it is equal to your number:

```
dim i as integer
for i = 2 to listLength +  2
    If Range("E" & i) = 160248 Then 
         Range("AG" & i) = "Yes"
    Else
         Range("AG" & i) = "No"
    End If
Next
```

If you wish to scan for different numbers you can adapt the code to use a value from a cell in which you enter that number, OR use an inputbox to enter the number you want to look for, or something else. This code was not tested.

If you want to use the column name you assigned instead of AG (which is safer) you can use something along the lines of:

```
 = Range("Incorporated_160248")(i+1)
```

Instead, which gives the column with an offset of i. Should bring you to the right cell.

Comment: I tried the following code:
`Sub TagTryco()


Dim listLength
listLength = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 1

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To listLength + 2

    If Range("E" & i) = 160248 Then

         Range("TrycoIncorporated_160248")(i + 1) = "Yes"

    Else
         Range("TrycoIncorporated_160248")(i + 1) = "No"
    End If

Next


End Sub`

and received Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference on .Cells
I placed the code up in the question for readability.

Comment: I placed the code I tried up in the question for readability. Got a compile error and I know you stated the code had not been tested. So, it does fail on .Cells  Thanks for your tutelage!

Comment: Do I need the Sheetname?
`FinalRow = Sheets("SheetNameHere").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry I copy/pasted a piece of code I had and skipped over that. You DO need to specify the sheet before the "." I was using that line within a "with" statement, so I didn't need to. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Now I got it to Subscript out of Range error as noted in question.

Comment: @ David GM, I put the new code at the bottom of the question and now I am getting Subscript out of range, has to be something very simple, trying to investigate now.

Comment: That means the loop goes too far. In that case, in the VBE (where you write the code) make you you see the Execution window. If you don't see it you have to get it to show, and I think in English the tab name should be 'View'? It's the third tab up top. When you have the execution window, add debug.print i at the end of the loop. It will print it each loop and you'll see where it goes out of range. It probably just goes 1 space too far, though.

Comment: Also, I believe the sheet's name needs to be in between quotations! That could also be a problem. It should be the name you see in the spreadsheet, not the actual name of the worksheet. Both work, but one requires Sheets("sheetname").Cells whereas the other requires sheetid.Cells (no quotations).

Comment: @ David GM, BAMMMM that worked, thank you very much for your insight and perseverance in helping me! Sweetness!